# Subversion EADDRINUSE on Mac

Tags: macos, svn, svnserve

I have a subversion server (accessed by svn://server/directory) that I've been using for years from multiple Windows systems.  I'm now doing some development on a Mac, and cannot get svn to access that server, even with a simple command such as

```
svn list svn://server/directory
```

(server and directory names change to protect the guilty)

All svn commands hang and have to be killed. (^c doesn't work, I have to ^z and kill...) Checking the console tool the last message is:

```
kernel: tcp_connect: inp=0xffffff801db54ac0 err=EADDRINUSE
```

Checking the server, the svnserve process is listening on port 3690.  So I did a netstat -a on my mac, and there is nothing listed for port 3690.

That's the end of the hints I've found in a couple hours of searching. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: hmmmm what do you see on a sudo lsof -i -P | grep 3690

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you're running the server on the mac or on some other machine.  The one thing I will note is that the Mac holds ports open briefly after apps have closed and that can trigger problems with restarting apps.

Comment: thekbb: It returns nothing.

Ben: The server is running on an other machine (a linux server).  I saw some notes about the mac holding ports open, but I'm only running a single command. Any "restarting" is within the svn client.  Is there some configuration or setting that would change this behavior?

Comment: Ok wait... Port 3690 is the port on the server. Is this error message indicating that port 3690 on the server system is "in use"?  That could happen if the Mac is holding a port that is connected to that port open, right?  But that won't be port 3690 on my end...  Right. I'm still stuck, if anyone has any hints, even of a web resource or book to check out, I'd greatly appreciate it.  My TCP/socket knowledge is really rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  I have a DNS lookup problem.  If I ping my server system, the address it tries to contact is not the IP address of that system.  I added the hostname into my /etc/hosts table and voila! It now works.

Whew!